# TiledMap Layers causing many extra texture bindings

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I'm using Tiled Map Editor to generate a tile map for my game in libgdx. I noticed while creating a simple map that having two tile layers causes many extra texture bindings. I'm using 2 packed tilesets and NOT using individual pngs.

For example, here is map with 2 tile layers with 2 tilesets. The dirt is from 1 tileset, while the rocks, trees, and other objects are on a different tileset.
[image: 2 layers]

This causes 25 texture bindings.

However, if I delete the layer with the rocks, trees, etc. and only leave the dirt, I get 1 texture binding.

[image: 1 layer]

Is there a better way to achieve this? Again, I'm not using individual pngs for the tiles, they are packed into 2 tilesets. What are the work arounds for this? To just pack everything into 1 tileset? I have some maps that are causing 80+ texture bindings.

Not really doing anything weird to render the map either:

```
class MapRenderer {

    private TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

    public MapRenderer(TiledMap tiledMap, float tiledMapScale,  Camera camera) {

        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap, tiledMapScale);
        tiledMapRenderer.setView((OrthographicCamera) camera);
    }

    public void update() {

        tiledMapRenderer.render();
    }
}
```

Sort of seems like it is rendering each tile, tile by tile. When a better way to reduce texture bindings would be to render each tile by tileset.

Comment: You pretty much answered the question yourself - "better way to reduce texture bindings would be to render each tile by tileset.". So yeah, the easiest way - "to just pack everything into 1 tileset". Or you could sort tiles somehow, so that first you draw all tiles from one tileset, then from another, etc.

Comment: few clarifying questions: 1) Why do you say "if I delete the layer with the rocks..." when on the screenshot it's the dirt layer that was deleted? 2) Do you get 1 texture binding, if you delete any of the layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the tiled map, create separate layer for tiles from each tileset. This way you will have only 1 extra binding for each tileset.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you saying that each layer should only have tiles from one tileset? If so, that still causes a bunch of texture bindings.

Comment: That's odd. If you look at OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer.render() implementation, you'll see that layers are drawn one after another, so if each layer contains tiles from only from one tileset (from one texture, to be exact), number of texture bindings should be equal to number of tilesets. Ok, in a few hours I'll take a closer look at how Tiled Map Editor generates maps, and will let you know if I find the reason.

Comment: Sorry, tried this again and I was wrong. If all of the textures in the layer are from 1 tileset, then you only get one binding. Kind of drag though, but I guess I'll have to work with it.